# flutter router : The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

in my router.dart
it is showing me this error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

for the (settings.name)

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case LoginViewRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(
        routeName: settings.name,
        viewToShow: LoginView(),
      );
    case SignUpViewRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(
        routeName: settings.name,
        viewToShow: SignUpView(),
      );
    case HomeViewRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(
        routeName: settings.name,
        viewToShow: HomeView(),
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `settings.name` with `settings.name!` or change `String routeName` to `String? routeName` in _getPageRoute.

For more info : https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 1):

Move the cursor over RouteSetting and press f12. Convert the name field from String to String? in the file you went to. Or at the end of the setting.name in the switch ! add sign. like (setting.name!)

Answer (score 0):

Check some points with `null safety` declaration of data member of class. And also check out the type of `action parameter` what it takes- It may take `String type` of data then update your variables/data member accordingly.

Please look into the concept of `null safety`.

Comment: Thank you , can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587281/flutter-navigation-debuglocked-is-not-true