# Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

Some one can help me. Error Message: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

[image]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Check my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71555669/flutter-router-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter/71555872#71555872

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798782/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-stri)

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Null Safely` code as this:

```
action = Uri.base.queryParameters['action']!; // add ! mark
```

The same process for all errors:

```
encryptedEmailAddress = Uri.base.queryParameters['encryptedEmailAddress']!; // add ! mark
doctorUID = Uri.base.queryParameters['doctorUID']!; // add ! mark
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart supports sound null safety.
Try using something like

`String nonNullableString = nullableString ?? 'default';`

OR

`actions=uri.base.queryParameters["key"]!`

Comment: You can find more info in
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92792

Comment: Which part do I need to change this code?

Comment: In all the 3 places you are getting. use `actions=uri.base.queryParameters["key"]!`

Answer (score 1):

Check some points with null safety declaration of data member of class. And also check out the type of action parameter what it takes- It may take String type of data then update your variables/data member accordingly.

Please look into the concept of null safety.

Answer (score 1):

As dart uses sound null safety, there are chances that the value in `Uri.base.queryParameters["actions"]` can be null. This is something that Flutter has adapted from the Swift programming language.

So basically, there are 2 ways you can solve this problem.

1. Using the null check.

```dart
final String? actions = Uri.base.queryParameters["actions"];
if (actions == null) {
/// The value of [actions] is null
return;
}
/// Continue with your coding...
```

2. By providing an optional value.

```dart
final String _actions = Uri.base.queryParameters["actions"] ?? "defaultValue";
```

I hope you understood what I am trying to say.

If you have any other doubts, do let me know.