# flutter navigation :: '!_debugLocked': is not true

Tags: firebase, flutter

So in my app I'm using a navigation service here :

```
class NavigationService {
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> get navigationKey => _navigationKey;

  void pop() {
    return _navigationKey.currentState.pop();
  }

  Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName, {dynamic arguments}) {
    return _navigationKey.currentState
        .pushNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments);

  }
}
```

and in order to toggle between login in and sign up I user this method :

```
  void navigateToSignup(){
    _navigationService.navigateTo(SignUpViewRoute);
  }
```

and in the  button :

```
  onPressed: (){
     model.navigateToSignup();
      },
```

when I run and try to click the button I get this error

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart':
Failed assertion: line 4028 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
```

I've read different solutions but not sure where to exactly do It in my app

Comment: One of the possibibilty of getting debugLocked is loop , while navigating  . Like `/loading`  page is pushing to `'/home` and `/home` is pushing to `/loading`

Comment: Try finding  any loop , if exist

Comment: @Manishyadav I can't find any loops , it is causing navigation problem in the whole app .. here is my code can you take a look ? https://github.com/shahad-jeza/green_app